# Request model throws stack overflow - .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the model NewOrderModel:

```
public class NewOrderModel
{
    private readonly List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> symbols = 
        new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string> ("WINZ19", "XBMF"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string> ("WDOZ19", "XBMF")
        };

    [Required]
    public string symbol
    {
        get => symbol;
        set
        {
            market = this.symbols.Find(findSymbol => findSymbol.Key == symbol).Value;
            symbol = value;
        }
    }

    public string market
    {
        get => market;
        private set
        {
            market = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Upon receiving a request, value of symbol loads the market field.

But when this Model gets called in the Controller, it throws an stack overflow (oh, the irony).
I suspect it could be some sort of recursion, but i don't see how it could be.

Can anyone point what i'm doing wrong here?

Comment: `get => market` `get => symbol`

Comment: You should be having backing fields for your propo. Currently property is calling same in getter which leads to stackover flow

Comment: Additionally, following the convention of UpperCasePropertyNames and camelCasePrivateFieldNames will help avoid this type if problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Overloading Getter and Setter Causes StackOverflow in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437791/overloading-getter-and-setter-causes-stackoverflow-in-c-sharp) or multiple other question about stackoverflow in getters/setters in C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your property getter are calling their self. You need to store the value in a backing field.

Also public properties follow PascalCase convention

I don't know what are you trying in the Symbol setter, perhaps it sould be (Note that you will need to add exception management in case the symbol value doesn't exists in the symbols list):

```
try {
   Market = this.symbols.Find(findSymbol => findSymbol.Key == value).Value;
   _symbol = value;
} catch {
   //Do exception handling
}
```

Here the complete code:

```
public class NewOrderModel
{
   private readonly List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> symbols = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
   {
      new KeyValuePair<string, string> ("WINZ19", "XBMF"),
      new KeyValuePair<string, string> ("WDOZ19", "XBMF")
   };

  private string _symbol;

  [Required]
  public string Symbol
   {
      get => _symbol;

      set
       {
          Market = this.symbols.Find(findSymbol => findSymbol.Key == value).Value;
          _symbol = value;
        }
    }

    private string _market;   
    public string Market
        {
            get => _market;

            private set
            {
                _market = value;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Exactly what i needed! Thank you very much :)