# StackOverflowException: The requested operation caused a stack overflow

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, exception, overflow, stack-overflow

I've made some code in Unity2d with c# and interface.
LevelingSystem.cs is putted in empty gameobject.

And i getting error:

```
StackOverflowException: The requested operation caused a stack overflow.
PlayerCap.get_actExp () (at Assets/Scripts/player/PlayerCap.cs:17)
PlayerCap.get<message truncated>
```

CapLevel.cs

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


interface ICapLevel
{

    float multiplierA { get; set; }
    float multiplierB { get; set; }
    float multiplierC { get; set; }
    float multiplierD { get; set; }

    int lvlCap { get; set; }
    List<double> expCap { get; set; }
    float actExp { get; set; }

    void GenerateExpPerLvl();
    float RequiredExp(int level);
}
```

PlayerCap.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerCap : ICapLevel
{

    public float multiplierA { get { return multiplierA; } set { multiplierA = 280f; } }
    public float multiplierB { get { return multiplierB; } set { multiplierB = 100f; } }
    public float multiplierC { get { return multiplierC; } set { multiplierA = 1.15f; } }
    public float multiplierD { get { return multiplierD; } set { multiplierD = 2.3f; } }

    public int lvlCap { get { return lvlCap; } set { lvlCap = 210; } }

    public List<double> expCap { get { return expCap; } set { expCap = new List<double>(); } }
    public float actExp { get { return actExp; } set { actExp = 0f; } }

    public void GenerateExpPerLvl()
    {
        Debug.Log("implementation successful");

        for (int expLevel = 1; expLevel <= lvlCap; expLevel++)
        {
            expCap.Add(RequiredExp(expLevel - 1));
        }

    }

    public float RequiredExp(int level)
    {
        double formulaRounded;
        var formula = multiplierB * (Mathf.Pow(multiplierC, level - 1)) + multiplierA * (Mathf.Pow(level, multiplierD));
        if (formula < 1000)
        {
            if ((formula % 10) == 0)
            {
                formulaRounded = formula;
                return (float)formulaRounded;
            }
            else
            {
                formulaRounded = Math.Round((formula / 1000), 1, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            formulaRounded = Math.Round((formula / 1000), 0, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
        }
        return (float)formulaRounded * 1000;

    }
}
```

LevelingSystem.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class LevelingSystem : MonoBehaviour
{
    //interface implementation
    private PlayerCap _pCap;
    private ICapLevel _ICap;

    private List<double> _pExpCap;

    private int pLvl;
    private float _pActExp;

    public void Awake()
    {
        _pCap = new PlayerCap();
        _ICap = _pCap;


    }

    private void Start()
    {
        _pActExp = _ICap.actExp;
        _ICap.GenerateExpPerLvl();
        _pExpCap = _ICap.expCap;
    }



    public void AddExp(float amount)
    {
        _pActExp += amount;
        StartCoroutine(CapLevelCheck(amount));
    }

    private IEnumerator CapLevelCheck(float amount)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (_pActExp >= _pExpCap[pLvl])
            {
                _pActExp -= (float)_pExpCap[pLvl];
                AddLevel(1);
            } else
            {
                Debug.Log("You Get " + amount + " Experience and you have " + pLvl + " Lvl. *Click noice!");
                break; //otherwise loop will do in infinite
            }
            yield return 0;
        }
    }

    public void AddLevel(int amount)
    {
        pLvl += amount;
    }
    public int GetActualLevel()
    {
        return pLvl;
    }
}
```

Im try few things like get rid off for in method GenerateExpPerLvl() and error gones away so my suspicious thing  is list variable but maybe im wrong.

Thanks for help :)

Comment: There are bazillion questions about stackoverflow on getter/setter why you are asking another? obviosuly you are calling getter inside gettrer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Overloading Getter and Setter Causes StackOverflow in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437791/overloading-getter-and-setter-causes-stackoverflow-in-c-sharp)

Comment: `public List<double> expCap { get { return expCap; } set { expCap = new List<double>(); } }
    public float actExp { get { return actExp; } set { actExp = 0f; } }`both these suffer from recursion also it means you cant change the value as it will always set specific values rather than actual values..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
public float actExp { get { return actExp; } set { actExp = 0f; } }
                                // ^ Problem here & ^ same problem here
```

You are calling your *Property* inside its own getter and setter. It creates an infinite loop... (everytime you call `actExp` it will call itself)

Instead you should just write (if there is no logic inside accessors):

```
public float actExp { get; set; }
```